# Disconnect the integration tracking user in Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I need to disconnect the integration tracking user and re connect again in Marketing cloud both at BU level and Enterprise level. How to go ahead to implement this. How can we disconnect the tracking user, do i need to delete the tracking user in salescloud and create a new one ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can now disconnect the **Marketing Cloud Connector** yourself via the UI.  Go to the Salesforce Integration option on the Admin tab.  You will need to click the **edit** button in the top left of this page before you can disconnect.

If you are connecting to a different ORG that has a different data schema than what was previously used, then I would recommend contacting SFMC Support.  They will be able to clear out any residual meta data for you.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the Disconnect Account option, in my ET instance. This holds true for Enterprise as well as BU level. Refer to the screen shot attached. I have multi org feature enabled in my account.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact SFMC Support to cleanly disconnect on the SFMC side.  You can break the connection yourself, but some of the old attribute mappings will cause issues.

Comment: Could you please mention how to break the connection by myself. If i go to Salesforce Integration in Marketing cloud i can not change the tracking user. Then how can i go ahead with breaking the connection

Comment: Do you have user rights to edit the setting in the Salesforce Integration tab?  Also, do you know what version of the connector you are using?  It maybe that this is only available in version 5 or greater.